# Why has the second script stopped working?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nMCl5iTkSz6YaMcXKL4dywf6HONVohtmLyY9HZfFBUo/edit?usp=sharing)

youll notice there are two scripts, Page1 and Page2, I did delete their triggers so theyll have to be manually ran to do anything. Page1 used to update the IDs on "Live", and Page 2 would update "Live 2", they used to work in alongside of eachother, but now seem to have stopped, despite the fact I havent changed anything.

Thanks in advance for any help (and sorry for my english)

Here is the error that appears when running Page2,

```
    [20-04-05 23:04:48:376 BST] TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValues' of null
at getVideoIds(Code:27:22)
at updateStats(Code:18:18)
```

This is the code for both of the scripts, the only difference being the sheet name and the data ID name.

```
// This is "Sheet1" by default. Keep it in sync after any renames.
var SHEET_NAME = 'Live';

// This is the named range containing all video IDs.
var VIDEO_ID_RANGE_NAME = 'IDs';

// Update these values after adding/removing columns.
var Column = {
  VIEWS: 'C',
  LIKES: 'D',
  DISLIKES: 'E',
  COMMENTS: 'F',
  DURATION: 'G'
};

function updateStats() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var videoIds = getVideoIds();
  var stats = getStats(videoIds.join(','));
  writeStats(stats);
}

// Gets all video IDs from the range and ignores empty values.
function getVideoIds() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(VIDEO_ID_RANGE_NAME);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var videoIds = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];
    if (!value) {
      return videoIds;
    }
    videoIds.push(value);
  }
  return videoIds;
}

// Queries the YouTube API to get stats for all videos.
function getStats(videoIds) {
  return YouTube.Videos.list('contentDetails,statistics', {'id': videoIds}).items;
}

// Converts the API results to cells in the sheet.
function writeStats(stats) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var durationPattern = new RegExp(/PT((\d+)M)?(\d+)S/);
  for (var i = 0; i < stats.length; i++) {
    var cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.VIEWS + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.viewCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.LIKES + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.likeCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.DISLIKES + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.dislikeCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.COMMENTS + (2+i));
    cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.commentCount);
    cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.DURATION + (2+i));
    var duration = stats[i].contentDetails.duration;
    var result = durationPattern.exec(duration);
    var min = result && result[2] || '00';
    var sec = result && result[3] || '00';
    cell.setValue('00:' + min + ':' + sec);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Comment: I’ve added the code.

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: The error message is above the script, it doesn’t update the page “Live 2”

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a named range that does not exist in this line:

```js
var range = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(VIDEO_ID_RANGE_NAME_2);
```

If you list all the ranges in your spreadsheet, you will notice that there is no named range called `Test` — in this case, `Test` is preceded by the sheet name: `'Live 2'!Test`:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ss.getNamedRanges().forEach(namedRange => console.log(namedRange.getName()))
```

I suggest you to avoid naming the ranges in this way, to avoid problems like this. In any case, you can fix this by changing the value that is assigned to `VIDEO_ID_RANGE_NAME_2`:

```js
var VIDEO_ID_RANGE_NAME_2 = "'Live 2'!Test";
```

#### Notes:

- Not sure if your script will run smoothly now, but your current issue should be fixed by this small modification.
- It doesn't make sense to have to scripts that do exactly the same. I'd consider having only one of them, and provide different arguments to the corresponding functions depending on whether you want to work on `Page1` or `Page2`.

#### Reference:

- [Spreadsheet.getNamedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getnamedranges)